# Selenium Firefox Driver: driver.Quit / driver.Close does not close the File Upload window

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a test that does the following:

1. Loads a webpage
2. Clicks an "upload" button that opens the Windows native file picker dialog/window
3. Uploads a file by typing in the filename path in the window and closes the dialog using the {ENTER} key. (Using AutoItX)

```
    if(AutoItX.WinActive(fileuploadwindowtitle) == 0)
    {
        AutoItX.WinActivate(fileuploadwindowtitle, "");
    }
    
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    AutoItX.Send(filename);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

4. Proceeds to do other stuff in the UI (checks the image thumbnail to assert that the upload was correct, etc)

Sometimes the process may fail during step 3 for multiple reasons (e.g. the typing of the file path was interrupted, or the file does not exist so the dialog did not close upon pressing {ENTER}).

The test fails eventually, and calls the `[Teardown]` which essentially is just `driver.Quit();` right now . What I noticed is that even when the main browser window is closed, the file upload dialog still remains open, causing interference with the succeeding tests in the playlist.

At first I tried to debug and iterate through all the window handles from the driver, but it turns out there is only a handle for the main window, and not the upload dialog, so this approach did not work for me.

Is there a way to ensure that the file dialog becomes closed before the call for `driver.Quit()`?

Comment: Is your test interacting with an `<input type="file">` element? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML.

Comment: And why not set the value of the file input using `SendKeys(fileName)`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the close button tag of a dialog in the html page.

`<a id="TANGRAM__PSP_closeBtn" class="close-btn"></a>`

now you can use selenium to locate the element and close the dialog.

through click the close button, you can close the dialog before another operation.

view the document
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#find-elements-from-element

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "TANGRAM__PSP_closeBtn")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "TANGRAM__PSP_closeBtn").click()
```